# How to call one logic app from other logic app which currently located in different subscription

Tags: c#, azure-logic-apps

I have a requirement to call the logic app from other logic app which is located in a different subscription. how can I call?

I know how to call one logic app from other logic app when both are in the same subscription. How can I call if it is in different subscription?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34129.azure-logic-apps-call-nested-logic-apps-directly-from-logic-apps-designer.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTTP trigger 'When a HTTP request is received'. With this you can define a schema. After the logic app is deployed you a link will be generated with a token in the url. Just call this URL from your first logic app. The URL will contain api-version,sp,sv and a sig. Hope it helps to get you started.
[image]